# Having issues seperating the required data using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex on a rails application I'm building to seperate input without splitting the string up manually.

My regex is:

```
(?<action>\S+)(?:\s(?<query>.*)\s)(?<id>(?<=.).*?(?=\s))
```

And the test data I am using is as follows:

```
add hello by name
remove first second by id
add first
```

From this, I want the following values:

```
action: add, query: hello, id: name
action: remove, query: first second, id: id
action: add, query: first, id: nil (or "")
```

What am I doing wrong? It won't match at all on the last line of test data. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?<action>\S+)(?:\s(?<query>(?:(?! by ).)*))(?: by (?<id>\w+))?
```

The `id` is always preceded by `" by "`, so each character in your `<query>` group should repeat a negative lookahead for that `" by "` substring.

Also ensure that the group around the `id` is optional, so that the third line gets matched as well.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQORWb/1)

Another option, instead of repeating a negative lookahead, would be to have a single positive lookahead for `" by "` or the end of the string, and repeat lazily:

```
^(?<action>\S+)(?:\s(?<query>.*?(?= by |$)))(?: by (?<id>\w+))?$
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for explaining it so well, it works great!